# can't insert data to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I can connect fine in Netbeans using this:

```
 Connection conn = null;
 try{
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarymangementsystem","root","root");
     if(conn!= null)
     {
     System.out.println("connected");
     }
 }catch(Exception e)
             {
             System.out.println("not connected");
             }
}
```

But when it comes to adding data to the columns, i just cant.

```
try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarymangementsystem","root","root");
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String Query = "INSERT into librarian_details(username, name, email, password) VALUES("+ uname +", "+ fname +", " + emails + ",  " + psword +")";
        stmt.executeUpdate(Query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success!");
     }
```

Anyone knows the problem?
Updated Problem:

> String Query = "insert into book_details(Book_Name, ISBN, Author, Category, >Quantity, BookShelfNo,Row,Column) VALUES('" +bookname + "','" + ISBN + "','" + >AuthorName + "','" + Category + "','" + Quantity + "','" + ?BookShelfNo +"', '" >+ Row + "', '" + Column + "')";

I cant seem to insert any data to Row and Column using this:

> String Row = jTextField9.getText();
>   String Column = jTextField10.getText();
>   Row and Column Datatype is int.

Comment: In your catch statement, do a `e.printStackTrace()` and paste what you get in the question.

Comment: mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'flores, asdfgh,  admin)' at line 1
i got this error when inserting.

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate values into a query string like this. It is **unsafe** (search for SQL injection), instead you should parametrize your query and use a `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the username, name, email and password fields are of **String type** and Data type used while creating the columns username, name, email and password of librarian_details is **Varchar** .

If so, then you need to update your query string to the below code:

```
String Query = "INSERT into librarian_details(username, name, email, password) 
VALUES('"+ uname +"','"+ fname +"','" + emails + "','" + psword +"')";
```

If your input String has an **apostrophe (')** character then you need to add an extra apostrophe (') character as an escape sequence.

For Example:your password is abc'aa

```
        String uname = "abc";
        String fname = "xyz";
        String emails = "abc@xyz.com";
        String psword = "abc''aa";//extra apostrophe (') character added
        String Query = "INSERT into librarian_details(username, name, email, password) VALUES('"+ uname+ "','"+ fname+ "','"+ emails+ "','"+ psword+ "')";
```

**Note:** Adding extra apostrophe (') to the existing (') character is different than a double quote.

Below code is for your updated query

```
        String bookname ="abc";
        String ISBN="qwerty123";
        String AuthorName="user3213";
        String Category="New";
        String Quantity="1";
        String BookShelfNo="5";
        int Row=1;
        int Column=5;

        String Query = "insert into book_details(Book_Name, ISBN, Author, Category, Quantity, BookShelfNo,`Row`,`Column`) VALUES('" +bookname + "','" + ISBN + "','" + AuthorName + "','" + Category + "','" + Quantity + "','" + BookShelfNo +"', " + Row + ", " + Column + ")";
        stmt.execute(Query);
```

**Note:** you are using reserved keywords of sql like Row and Column.
I guess your column names in DB are Book_Name, ISBN, Author, Category, Quantity, BookShelfNo, Row and Column.

**Suggestion:**

- Using PreparedStatement will save your time for writing a query (no need to remember datatype of variable and columns.)
- PreparedStatement uses query caching functionality.
- Hence, execution is faster than simple statement.

Below code depicts the usage of prepared statement for your query.

```
        //query parameters will be dynamically set 
        String Query = "INSERT INTO book_details VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        //create a Prepared statement using connection object.
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(Query);

        //assign the query parameter values
        pstmt.setString(1, bookname);
        pstmt.setString(2, ISBN);
        pstmt.setString(3, AuthorName);
        pstmt.setString(4, Category);
        pstmt.setString(5, Quantity);
        pstmt.setString(6, BookShelfNo);
        pstmt.setInt(7, Row);
        pstmt.setInt(8, Column);
        //display query string generated by PreparedStatement.
        System.out.println("Query: "+pstmt.toString());
        //Display result; result=1 means success.
        int result = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("result: "+result);
```

Comment: But it won't work if the `password` contains an apostrophe (`'`).

Comment: can you help me again?

Comment: This is bad advice, instead the OP should use parametrized queries with prepared statements. That removes the need to escape values like this.

Comment: which java and sql datatypes are used in the updated query. I need bookname , ISBN , AuthorName ,Category ,Quantity ,BookShelfNo , Row and Column.

Comment: Looks like '장나라' is a beginner to JDBC. Let him try first with simple java.sql.Statement, later on can move on to prepared statements.

Comment: I assume the datatypes used are String and varchar.

Comment: Yep all of it except for row and column. Im a beginner/student at java.

Comment: are you sure the column name is ">Quantity" and not "Quantity"? the angle bracket?

Comment: Sorry, that's just a mistake. its Quantity. ok so here's what i tried

Comment: Yep, weird its all working now rename the Row and Column,thank you for helping and sorry for wasting your time a lot.

Comment: I suggest you to go through this tutorial for JDBC  http://javatpoint.com/java-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Escape the text values or even better - use prepared statements.

```
String Query = "INSERT into librarian_details(username, name, email, password) 
VALUES('"+ uname +"', '"+ fname +"', '" + emails + "', '" + psword +"')";
```

Prepared statements:

```
String Query = "INSERT into librarian_details(username, name, email, password) 
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating values into a query is unsafe, it opens you up to SQL injection. You need to use a prepared statement instead:

```
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT into librarian_details(username, name, email, password) " 
        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    pstmt.setString(1, uname);
    pstmt.setString(2, fname);
    pstmt.setString(3, emails);
    pstmt.setString(4, psword);

    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```